# How to restrict execution of a feature file to once while using call with array parameter ( execute __loop 0 )

Tags: karate

Here is my situation:
I have a sequence of steps to create users based on a random input i.e between  1 - 5.
To do this , I have a js function that loops thru based on random input and call is made to a re-usable feature to create users. User-id is stored in a json array after every create user request as I need to active these users later.

This is the output I get from my user creation steps

- def userIDs = [{id: user1}, {id: user2}, {id: user3}]

User activation steps:
Here I am calling a reusable feature with above generated array with userIDs parameter.

- def result = call read('r_userActivation.feature') userIDs

I have a js function in r_userActivation feature to generate dynamic payload for user activation request based on no. of users created. Payload is something like this

```
<users>
    <user>user1</user>
    <user>user2</user>
    <user>user3</user>
</users>
```

As my parameter is array, feature file that I am calling is trying to execute in loop to the extent of my array length.

Is there a way to restrict call statement execution __loop to once as I don't need my request to loop.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-shape the data:

```
* def users = { ids: '#(userIDs)' }
```

Also look at JSON transforms: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

Comment: Thank you. Exactly, I was working on re-shaping data. Kudos to you for making automation easy and quick. It's just few days that I started with Karate, knock on wood; it's going great !!!